# Any way to move two symmetrical edges / vertices / faces in opposite directions?

Tags: modeling

I know of the mirror modifier, but say i just want to quickly select a pair (or multiple pairs) of symmetrical vertices / edges / faces of a model. A sword crossguard for example.

Is there anyway i can just simply select two edges / faces / vertices and transform them in opposite directions instead of in the same direction? (So that i can quickly and easily tweak a model without having to apply a mirror modifier)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your model is aligned with one of the axes, you can **scale** your components (edges / verts / faces) along that axis if your [pivot point is set to median point](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/pivot_point/median_point.html) (default).

[image: Scale to Transform]